# PHP - merging arrays

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have two arrays...

```
$arr1 = array(
    'name',
    'date' => array('default' => '2009-06-13', 'format' => 'short'),
    'address',
    'zipcode' => array('default' => 12345, 'hidden' => true)
);

$arr2 = array(
    'name',
    'language',
    'date' => array('format' => 'long', 'hidden' => true),
    'zipcode' => array('hidden' => false)
);
```

Here's the desired result:

```
$final = array(
    'name',
    'date' => array('default' => '2009-06-13', 'format' => 'long', 'hidden' => true),
    'zipcode' => array('default' => 12345, 'hidden' => false)
);
```

- Only the elements from $arr2 (that also exist in $arr1) are used
- Each element's attributes are merged
- If a common element (e.g. zipcode) shares an attribute (e.g. hidden), then the attribute from $arr2 takes precedence

What are some good approaches for solving this problem?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: I tried to hobble something together... critiques welcomed:**

```
$new_array = array_intersect_key($arr2, $arr1);

foreach ($new_array as $key => $val)
{
    if (is_array($arr1[$key]))
    {
        if (is_array($val))
        {
            $new_array[$key] = array_merge($val, $arr1[$key]);
        }
        else
        {
            $new_array[$key] = $arr1[$key];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good practice in this case is to post code like that as an answer to your own question.

Comment: The problem is that the above "solution" doesn't work...

Comment: I was looking at this but am wondering about a slight inconsistency. You only care about matching for the first-dimension of the array, and then merge everything in the second dimension, overwriting? Also, will this ever extend past two dimensions?

Comment: This will never extend past two dimensions. And yes, the $arr1's element's attributes will get overwritten by any matching $arr2 attributes.

Comment: My updated solution should be fixed now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close

```
$newArr = array_intersect_key($arr1, $arr2);
foreach ($newArr as $key => $val)
{
    if (is_array($val))
    {
        $newArr[$key] = array_merge($arr1[$key], $arr2[$key]);
    }
}
```

**Edit**
Just had to change the array_intersect to array_intersect_key

Comment: That doesn't look quite right either. If $arr1['address'] is an array, then it still makes it to the final output... :\

Comment: I didn't really check it throughly, it just gave me the proper result so I stopped :x. Let me have another look.

Answer (score 0):

you might find array_intersect() useful

[link text](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

Comment: I'm assuming he knows about the function by the fact a subset of such is included in his example code.